# How does the bolt power work with the Gatling Shotgun?

Tags: savage-worlds, powers

My GM is telling me that when I use the Bolt power with the Gatling Shotgun, the normal shooting ROF is lost, and only the one power bolt is used. This does not make sense to me. Especially since both bullets are being replaced with the std. 2 bolts.

My understanding is that it holds 12 bullets and shoots 2 at a time. Am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: Sorry if it's obvious, but could you explain how you're combining a Power with a gun?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie is right here. As it stands this question doesn't make much sense as there isn't a way of combining Bolt with a weapon by RAW

Comment: @Wibbs I'm 95% sure this about trappings.

Answer (score 2):

The situation you describe is rather unusual. Savage Worlds has the concept of trappings. These alter the look, feel and sometimes mechanics of a power.

For example a cold trapping for a Bolt might lower the damage, but make the ground under foot slippery.

The general idea when you are creating and using your own trappings is that any mechanical changes must be balanced so that advantages such as the chance of setting something on fire are offset by appropriate disadvantages, such as an increased Power Point cost.

In Deadlands however, trappings are largely predefined and a lot less flexible. You can see this by looking at the power descriptions in the Deadlands Player Guide, which describes the trappings for each type of magic user for each power.

So where does that leave us for your situation? Well there are two situations I can see.

### Mad Scientists

If the magic user is a Mad Scientist then options open up. Of all magic users, these are the most flexible, as they get to design their trappings from scratch based on the device they have for each power. If this is the case and you have a Mad Scientist who has built a Gatling Shotgun Bolt device using a lot of the Gatling shooting mechanics, it is up to the GM and player to come up with the mechanics of how that works and make sure it is balanced. If you feel that these mechanics are more powerful than those of the standard Bolt power, then you would need to offset those with an appropriate disadvantage.

### Other Arcane Backgrounds

If the magic user is not a Mad Scientist, then by RAW the options are almost non-existent. As @MrLemon describes in his answer, the only thing possible here given the inflexibility of trappings by RAW in Deadlands is to have the shotgun as a fluff trapping only. This means that none of the actual mechanics for the Bolt power would change, and the shotgun only comes up as part of the descriptive aspect of the power.

As a final comment, it should be noted that some GMs do make the trappings to powers in Deadlands more flexible by ignoring/altering those written in the Players Guide. If you do this though, you are pretty much on your own in making sure any mechanical changes are balanced. If you go down this road though, try to make sure you preserve the individuality of each of the Arcane backgrounds, as this is one of the main things trappings help with.

Answer (score 1):

When a character uses the Bolt power, what happens is exactly what the Bolt power describes as happening. Normally (but see below), that means you create 1-3 bolts dealing 2d6 or 3d6 damage each (in Savage Worlds Core Revised, your version may be different).

*Everything else* about the power is fluff that is decided upon by you (together with the GM and other players) when your character learns that power. This is known as the power's *Trapping*:

> **Trappings:** The powers listed in this chapter are
>   designed to be as simple to use and remember as
>   possible. This helps the Game Master remember what all
>   the powers do, and helps players remember the rules for
>   common powers even between different settings. But just
>   because these powers work the same from setting to
>   setting doesn’t mean they have to look the same or even
>   have the same names (at least among the characters of
>   the world).
>
> (Savage Worlds Core Revised, p. 81)

For example, a Bolt could be fluffed as small fireballs, or a ray-gun, or ballistic card throwing, basically whatever you'd like it to be. In your case, I understand Bolt is manifested through the shotgun. It could be fluffed as an alternate firing mode (such as a grenade launcher), or a targeted heat ray using the built-up heat of the gun, or magic bullets.

That said, the rules actively encourage GMs and players to slightly modify the powers to better reflect a trapping, such as a fireball Bolt setting stuff on fire, while an insect swarm Bolt does not. So there *may* be special rules for your gatling shotgun Bolt power as well, but not necessarily.

If you'd like to factor your weapon's ROF into the power, you can talk with your GM and work together to come up with a fair and balanced variant of this particular Bolt power. One way would be to say that you *have* to shoot a number of bolts equal to your ROF (unlike normally, where you can choose), but the damage is 2d8.